# Entity Framework many-to-many selection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

The model contains 2 entities with many-to-many relationship: [CatalogueItems and Keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XppTX.png).

Assume that 2 variables are defined:

```
ObjectQuery<Keyword> KW;
ObjectQuery<CatalogueItem> CI;
```

**KW** contains some query for selecting a set of keywords. I need to get **CI** that selects all CatalogueItems that have at least one Keyword from **KW**.

An important thing: nothing should be pre-computed or enumerated. Keywords enumeration takes a lot of time, but UI is based on live CatalogueItems displaying. A perfect thing would be to get **CI** ready for execution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from catalogueItem in CI
from keyword in KW
where catalogueItem.Keywords.Contains(keyword)
select catalogueItem
```

EDIT:
So that KW isn't calculated every time, try doing this:

```
var keywords = KW.ToList()
from catalogueItem in CI
from keyword in keywords
where catalogueItem.Keywords.Contains(keyword)
select catalogueItem
```

Otherwise, I'll need to see the query in KW and your whole database to be able to know how to optimize the query.

Another option would be to simply write a Stored Procedure and map it with Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks.

It works, but tooooooo slow. A single query for fetching keywords takes a couple of seconds.

This query is running... I don't know. I have been waining for 10 minutes, and turned it off. Looks like it recalculates KW for every CatalogueItem.

Also, CatalogueItems are repeated in the results. Distinct() doesn't help at all — app just hangs and gives no results in a reasonable time.

I believe there should be a more optimized way.

Comment: The query is like "keyword.Value like @0 or keyword.Value like @1 ...". Database has a transitional table (ItemID, KeywordID) for making many-to-many relation. Indexes are ok.
Perhaps SP is a better way to implement this... Pity

Answer (score 0):

```
context.CatalogueItems.Where(ci=> ci.Keywords.Where(cik=>KW.Any(cik)));
```

Something like that? Please check the syntax.

Comment: Something wrong :( It doesn't understand "cik" in the most inner brackets.